# Will be TRIM enabled by default?

Tags: ssd, trim

I heard that Ubuntu 14.04 will feature TRIM by default on SSDs. What I would like to know is that if in the current daily builds it is already activated.

Also, it would be appreciated a way to verify if it is indeed working.

Comment: Ubuntu +1 questions are off-topic here.  However it looks like it is, according to the last line of [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/trim-ssd-support-enabled-ubuntu-14-04?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=trim-ssd-support-enabled-ubuntu-14-04) post.  "After some extensive testing Ubuntu developer Martin Pitt announced on Google+ that “SSDs are now being trimmed automatically out of the box."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRIM will be run by a cronjob by default as [announced by Martin Pitt](https://plus.google.com/107564545827215425270/posts/D2SB1zxb9Z9). This will be done weekly (as can be seen [in the patch](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/159909618/util-linux_2.20.1-5.1ubuntu10_2.20.1-5.1ubuntu11.diff.gz)) and will be perfectly configurable. Automatic TRIMimg will be enabled.

Comment: Extra info: "Ubuntu users with Solid-State Drives have something extra to look forward to in April’s release of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: TRIM support is finally enabled by default." http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/trim-ssd-support-enabled-ubuntu-14-04